# Generators of multiplicative group of integers modulo a prime number $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

The problem is

> Find all generators of $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

**My attempt:**

Since $\varphi(17)=16$, we can check whether powers of integers from $2$ to $16$ modulo $17$ are cyclic of order $16$.

(mod $17$ are omitted)

$2^0=1, 2^1=2, 2^3=8, 2^4=16, 2^5=15, 2^6=13, 2^7=9, 2^8=1$,

so the order is not $16$, $2$ is not a generator. Since $2$ generates $4, 8, 16$, they are not generators either.

$3^0=1, 3^1=3, 3^2=9, 3^3=10, 3^4=13, 3^5=5, 3^6=15, 3^7=11, 3^8=16, 3^9=14, 3^{10}=8, 3^{11}=7, 3^{12}=4, 3^{13}=12, 3^{14}=2, 3^{15}=6, 3^{16}=1,$

so the order is $16$, $3$ is a generator.

$5^0=1, 5^1=5, 5^2=8, 5^3=6, 5^4=13, 5^5=14, 5^6=2, 5^7=10, 5^8=16, 5^9=12, 5^10=9, 5^{11}=11, 5^{12}=4, 5^{13}=20, 5^{14}=15, 5^{15}=7, 5^{16}=1,$

so $5$ is a generator.

$6^0=1, 6^1=6, 6^2=2, 6^3=12, 6^4=4, 6^5=7, 6^6=8, 6^7=14, 6^8=16, 6^9=11, 6^{10}=15, 6^{11}=5, 6^{12}=13, 6^{13}=10, 6^{14}=9, 6^{15}=3, 6^{16}=1,$

so $6$ is a generator.

…

**Question:**

Is there an easier way to do this problem?

Comment: Once you know that $3$ is a generator, you can say that the generators are the odd powers of $3$

Comment: It's also helpful to know that the *count* of generators ("primitive elements") for $(\mathbb Z/ p\mathbb Z)^*$ is $\varphi(\varphi(p)) = \varphi(p-1)$ when $p$ is prime.

Comment: So we have *eight* generators: $\{3,10,5,11,14,7,12,6\}$ in $U(17)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\mathbb Z/17\mathbb Z)^\times$ is a cyclic group with $16$ elements.

Once you know that $3$ is a generator, the generators are $3^n$ with $\gcd(n,16)=1$,

i.e., the odd powers of $3$.

(You already calculated all the powers of $3$, so you know what they are.)

Comment: May I ask why other generators have such relation with $3$?

Comment: Yes, it’s true in a cyclic group, for any generator, not just $3$

Comment: Sorry, I meant why the generators in $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^\times$ are of the form $3^n$ with gcd$(n,16)=1$.

Comment: Can you see that odd numbers are generators of the cyclic group $\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z$ under addition?